# how to call a method in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, cocoa

i want that when user input in search box then

this text is store in global variable and a method is called which in another class
 ,how should i do this.....
 any idea please

Thanks.....

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement the [UISearchBarDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

if you want to react on a finished input by user (read: after the user wrote something into the searchbar's textfield and pressed "search" on the keyboard) you have to implement

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```